# LabelField not displaying on os6 and os7 devices (only on os5)

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I have the following labelfield that I want to be clickable and also catch/handle its focus/unfocus events.

```
titleField = new LabelField(title,FOCUSABLE|USE_ALL_WIDTH){
            public void paint(Graphics graphics)
            {
                graphics.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                graphics.drawText(_title, 30,0);
                super.paint(graphics);
            }

             protected boolean navigationClick(int status,int time)
                {
                    if(panel != null) panel.takeAction();
                    return true;
                }

                protected void onFocus(int dir)
                {
                    super.onFocus(dir);
                    panel.setSelectedIndex(_index); 
                }

                protected void onUnfocus()
                {
                    if(!_collapse){
                    _prevIndex = _index;
                    panel.setPreviousSelectedIndex(_prevIndex);
                    }
                }
        };
```

So far, the code works as expected on my os5 simulators, but on os6/7 simulators, the labelfields just appear blank (I even tried removing the super.paint(graphics); call but still got the same results). Any ideas what's happening? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i figured it out... actually in my layout (horizontal) i have a checkboxfield then a labelfield.. for some strange reason the checkboxfield is taking up all the horizontal space on os6/7 simulators even though i did not specify USE_ALL_WIDTH. By overriding layout and specifying the dimensions for the checkboxfield, the layout's behaving properly now. Thanks for the tips :)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you remove `drawText` and call `setText` for label every time when you change `_title` field.

I see also that you don't call `super.onUnfocus()` it cause repaint issue.

Comment: if i dont call drawText in paint then how do i actually show the text? I added the super.onunfocus but still getting the same results.. on os5 simulators everything works well, on os6/7 simulators nothing shows.

Comment: if you call setText for your text than super.paint will draw text for you

Comment: i figured it out... actually in my layout (horizontal) i have a checkboxfield then a labelfield.. for some strange reason the checkboxfield is taking up all the horizontal space on os6/7 simulators even though i did not specify USE_ALL_WIDTH. By overriding layout and specifying the dimensions the layout's behaving properly now. Thanks for the tips :)

Comment: If you posted that you have checkbox and GorizontalFieldManager it would definitely help with answer :)